# python write_videofile results in a black screen video

Tags: python, moviepy

Code:

```
clip = ImageSequenceClip(new_frames, fps=fps1)
clip.write_videofile("out.mp4", fps=fps1)
```

TL;DR:
This code produces a black screen video.

where fps1 is from the original video I stitch on

I am trying to stitch a video using frames from many videos.
I created an array containing all the images in their respective place and then passed frame by frame on each video and assigned the correct frame in the array. When I acted that way the result was ok, but the process was slow so I saved each frame to a file and loaded it within the stitching process. Python throw an exception that the array is to big and I chunked the video into parts and saved each chunk. The result came out as a black screen, even thought when I debugged I could show each frame on the ImageSequenceClip correctly. I tried reinstalling moviepy. I use windows 10 and I converted all frames to png type.

Comment: try using opencv VideoWriter

Comment: @BajMile I tried and got into problems with fourcc, maybe I have some codecs problem?

Answer (score 0):

Well @BajMile was indeed right offering to use opencv.
What took me a while to realize is that I have to use only functions of opencv, also for the images I was opening and resizing.